# The least requirement for the atomic operation

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

I just wanna collect some **evidence-based** info about the requirement for the atomic operation.

e.g. (maybe not right, just some example)

> 1. at x86_64, when you write or read on the entry sizeof long and aligned by long, the operation is aotmic，because balabalabala ...
> 2. at x86_64, when you write or read bytes use gcc [atomic primitive](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html), your operation on these bytes will keep atomic.

Hope to receive and help :)

Comment: The real question is what *you* mean by "atomic operation", I guess.

Comment: @KerrekSB I wanna collect some evidence-based info about how to keep atomic in different envrionment, or when the operation is atomic. The answer may be not just only one.

Comment: What does this have to do with the `operating-system`? Don't forget that you also might need to map higher level instructions to lower level ones to know if their assembler counter-parts are atomic.

Comment: @RedX: You're right. Tag operating-system just means that maybe some implementation depends on some operating system. I'm novice of stackoverflow. Should I remove the tag 'operating system' ?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [Professional C++](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=sN_0ovp_yv4C&pg=PT806&lpg=PT806&dq=assignment+of+scalars+x86+c%2B%2B&source=bl&ots=LjEXj-GBKF&sig=rcdNDTUXms_fMJY4j6n3orInwKI&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=2sSUT4vBA6r3mAWc0dXVAQ&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> A simple assignment to a simple scalar variable typically requires no
>   synchronization. For example, on the x86, a 32-bit aligned value is
>   handled atomically at the hardware level and a single transaction
>   requires no explicit synchronization. For example, setting a Boolean
>   value to false to stop a thread requires no synchronization, but an
>   operation like ++, -- or op= for any given op requires
>   synchronization.

This doesn't answer all your questions, but is this part of what you were looking for?

Comment: yes, it is part of what i am looking for. Thank you for your answer :D

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the chip-level guarantees you will need to consult the technical manuals for those chips. On Intel check out the S[oftware Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) which has the compelete information on memory ordering. The definition of atomic in this case includes a memory ordering guarantee. The basic guarantees are listing in "Volume 3: 8.2 Memory Ordering", where additionally some functions are marked as behaving in an "atomic" fashion.

Note the complete details are complex and require a detailed understanding of the chip. This is why C and C++ now wrap them in higher level guarantees. You can of course consult those respective standards to see their guarantees.

Comment: "This is why C and C++ now wrap them in higher level guarantees.". You mean the compiler dependent primary atomic reaction like `__sync_balabala`? Are there cross platfom ones?

Comment: No, I mean the Atomics library present in C++11 and C11. In C++ this includes the `atomic` class, and in C a series of free functions. In particular they make memory order an explicit parameter and simplify the chip model to be easier to use.